# CSS vertical text centering

Tags: css

The smiley face (when you click the link) is a little towards the bottom (with respect to the black box) in the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/UzvWc/3/

HTML

```
<div id="message">:)</div>
```

CSS

```
#message {
    padding:0px;
    opacity:0.7;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    width:200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -150px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 200pt;
    display: none;
}
```

How can I have that smiley right in the center?

Comment: Please place code *in* the question if possible. JSFiddle is occasionally down and your question shouldn't depend on it.

Comment: @Warface... the only thing I don't like about your solution is that it seems like a hack... where did you get `45px` from?

Comment: @Warface: It works, but it's a hack. Any other solution?

Comment: Then continue to search, it maybe a hack but it works. Sometimes it's all it need :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this ?

http://jsfiddle.net/UzvWc/5/

HTML

```
<div id="message">:)</div><a id="showmessage" href="#">Show smiley</a>
```

CSS

```
#message {
    opacity:0.7;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    width:200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -150px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 200pt;
    display: none;
    padding-bottom:45px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add some `padding-bottom`.

I added `25px`.  Adjust as necessary.

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/UzvWc/19/